# Can't install node gc-stats

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, npm-install, node-gyp, node-pre-gyp

I have been trying to install (for the past 18 hours) `npm i gc-stats` in a node.js version 18.15.0 and windows but it gives me the next error:

```
PS C:\Users\fdesantiago\Documents\test> npm i gc-stats
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.17.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\fdesantiago\Documents\test\node_modules\gc-stats
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\fdesantiago\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.15.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\fdesantiago\Documents\test\node_modules\gc-stats\build\gcstats\v1.4.0\Release\node-v108-win32-x64\gcstats.node --module_name=gcstats --module_path=C:\Users\fdesantiago\Documents\test\node_modules\gc-stats\build\gcstats\v1.4.0\Release\node-v108-win32-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.13.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\fdesantiago\Documents\test\node_modules\gc-stats\build\gcstats\v1.4.0\Release\node-v108-win32-x64\gcstats.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/gcstats/v1.4.0/Release/node-v108-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for gc-stats@1.4.0 and node@18.15.0 (node-v108 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error self-signed certificate in certificate chain 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.0 found at "C:\Users\fdesantiago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.15.0/node-v18.15.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.15.0/node-v18.15.0-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fdesantiago\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.15.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)      
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3) 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\fdesantiago\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v18.15.0\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\fdesantiago\\Documents\\test\\node_modules\\gc-stats\\build\\gcstats\\v1.4.0\\Release\\node-v108-win32-x64\\gcstats.node" "--module_name=gcstats" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\fdesantiago\\Documents\\test\\node_modules\\gc-stats\\build\\gcstats\\v1.4.0\\Release\\node-v108-win32-x64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v108"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\fdesantiago\Documents\test\node_modules\gc-stats
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\fdesantiago\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.15.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\fdesantiago\Documents\test\node_modules\gc-stats\build\gcstats\v1.4.0\Release\node-v108-win32-x64\gcstats.node --module_name=gcstats --module_path=C:\Users\fdesantiago\Documents\test\node_modules\gc-stats\build\gcstats\v1.4.0\Release\node-v108-win32-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fdesantiago\Documents\test\node_modules\gc-stats\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\fdesantiago\\Documents\\test\\node_modules\\gc-stats\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\fdesantiago\Documents\test\node_modules\gc-stats
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\fdesantiago\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-12T02_02_05_614Z-debug-0.log
```

Searched on the web but there is only a thread on github regarding this issue an there is no answer, how can I install the gc-stats?